# What are these elegant fonts from an old French adress

Tags: font-identification

What are the two font used in the picture below? I think these are two fonts. I tried WhatTheFont and Identifont sites.

The image came from my customer. He found the image on http://www.123rf.com/.  He likes the font for his Business card.

[image]

Comment: Hi Tracie Mary! We have some [requirements](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/2366/8708) for font identification questions, please take a look and edit your question to include that information.

Comment: I agree with your assessment that this is two fonts. Which of the two are you looking for?

Comment: That's hand lettering.

Comment: You can easily find similar. Here's for the second one, in category "school": http://www.dafont.com/theme.php?cat=602&text=pres+la+Place&fpp=100&l[]=10&l[]=1&l[]=13&l[]=2&l[]=3 or Linoscript font isn't that far from this.  For the #1, you'll need to find similar and add some customisation. There's Dalliance, Belwe, interlude script, Black Chancery,  Caslon have a bit the old style but are still very different from your example.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect this is not a 'font' at all, but rather a sample of somebody's handwriting. Look closely at some of the duplicate letters (e.g. e), and you will notice there are subtle differences and ink blots. The differences are easily spotted in the full-size version of the image.

Comment: Any suggestions on a similar looking font(s) It is for a business card, so I need a font please. thanks!

Comment: @TracieMary go to myfonts.com and search for script fonts.